# Extract a specific line from a html request into a variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Create a GET request to load the HTML source
- Search the source to find a string, if the string is found then extract the whole line into a variable

I've searched everywhere to find out how to do this but people only explain how to extract the whole source or using a dictionary.

For example, using the WWE Page:

Source: view-source:http://network.wwe.com/video/v2525697583?contextType=wwe-show&contextId=wwe_nxt_uk&contentId=300687284&watchlistAltButtonContext=series

I want to extract the line that includes this string

```
http://thumbs.media.net.wwe.com/wwe/
```

Code:

```
def extract(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    text = html.text
    word = None
    for line in text:
        if 'http://thumbs.media.net.wwe.com/wwe/' in line:
            word = line
    return word
```

When I am carrying out the function the program will return None as first assigned.

*NOTE* I only need the first match, not every other match into the variable

Comment: So what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Updated the code now

Comment: Break early once you find the substring you're looking for. Add a `break` statement after `word = line`

Comment: just put the return inside the `if` indent

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Try printing `line` to make sure your substring actually appears.

Comment: It still returns None

Comment: Just checked, when I print line it returns every letter of the source one by one

Comment: So that means `text` is a single string, so `for line in text` is iterating through it character by character, since a string is a sequence of characters. Try `for line in text.split("\n"):` instead to split it into a list of lines before you iterate.

Comment: Notice also that your code will logically return the *last* match. You should stop iterating the first time your `if` hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def extract(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    searchstr = 'http://thumbs.media.net.wwe.com/wwe/' 
    for line in response.text.split("\n"):
        if searchstr in line:
            return line
    return None
```

Or, shorter:

```
def extract(url, searchstr):
    return next((line for line in requests.get(url).text.split("\n") if searchstr in line), None)

print(extract('http://www.url.com', 'http://thumbs.media.net.wwe.com/wwe/'))
```

Or even better with a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

```
def extract(url, searchstr):
    match = re.search(rf"^(.*{searchstr}.*)$", requests.get(url).text, re.MULTILINE)
    return match.group(1) if match else None

print(extract('http://www.url.com', 'http://thumbs.media.net.wwe.com/wwe/'))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. However, its giving me AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: The second method works but it's returning the entire list of lines that has the string in it, I only need the first

Comment: Sorry, there was a `.text` missing in the first one, fixed.

Comment: However, are you sure about the second one? This is perfectly working for me?

Comment: Yeah its still printing all of the matches, I only need one

Comment: Are you sure you only calls the method once? The `next` method should only return the first item found matching the statement... Also, what about the third option, with regex?

Comment: I've only called it once, is there a way to manipulate a string from the given response?

Comment: parse a string from the source